# How to find out multiple parallel actions are finished yet?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to do multiple parallel actions in a Angular component.
After any action (foo) I substribe to its result.

I try to find out if any action is running or finished with a variable (lock).

```
for (let a of myary)
{
    this.lock ++;
    this.foo (a).subscribe (resp =>
    {
        this.lock --;
    }
}
```

There should be a spinner/hourglass while any action is not finished.

```
<spinner *ngIf="lock > 0"></spinner>
```

But its not working that way. Seem slock is safe for that type of access.
How can I manage this the right way in Typescript/Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) rxjs operator to execute several calls in paralell

```
this.lock=myary.length
forkJoin(myary.map(a=>this.foo(a)))
    .subscribe((res:any[])=>{
       in res[0] you have the response to this.foo(myary[0])
       in res[1] you have the response to this.foo(myary[1])
       ....
       this.lock=0
    })
```

If you want show a serie of "steps" each time one foo is completed you can use [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) makes that when a "foo" is completed, this.lock decrement

```
this.lock=myary.length
forkJoin(myary.map(a=>this.foo(a).pipe(
       tap(_=>this.lock--)
     )))
    .subscribe((res:any[])=>{
       in res[0] you have the response to this.foo(myary[0])
       in res[1] you have the response to this.foo(myary[1])
       ....
    })
```